# How to access a checkbox status on Kivy without a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have to access a checkbox status on Kivy (Python), **without creating a function** (as suggested on Kivy docs).

I need something like "if checkbox.active == True: do something"

Is it possible?

#### Kivy's docs suggestion (with a function):

#### ==========================================

```
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox

# ...

def on_checkbox_active(checkbox, value):
    if value:
        print('The checkbox', checkbox, 'is active')
    else:
        print('The checkbox', checkbox, 'is inactive')

checkbox = CheckBox()
checkbox.bind(active=on_checkbox_active)
```

#### The beginning of my code:

#### ==========================

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        Screen.__init__(self, **args)

        self.label_1 = Label(text...)
        self.label_2 = Label(text...)

        self.add_widget(self.label_1)
        self.add_widget(self.label_2)


    def on_checkbox_active(checkbox, value):
        if value:
            print('The checkbox', check_invoices, 'is active')
        else:
            print('The checkbox', check_invoices, 'is inactive')
```

## ...

#### Where I need the checkbox status:

#### =================================

```
if last_approval_SUM == 5:
    last_approval_x = 1
else:
    if CHECKBOX_STATUS == True:
        last_approval_x = 0
    else:
        last_approval_x = 1
```

Comment: I think you should to add a variable that would be changed whenever a checkbox was changed. I'm not  similar with kivy, but my suggestion may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following working example illustrates accessing `CheckBox`'s state in a function.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: label_1
            text: "Label 1's text"
        Label:
            id: label_2
            text: "Label 2's text"
        CheckBox:
            id: checkbox
        Button:
            text: 'Set approval rating'
            on_release: root.set_approval_rating()
""")


last_approval_SUM = 0


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def set_approval_rating(self):

        if last_approval_SUM == 5:
            last_approval_x = 1
        else:
            if self.ids.checkbox.active:
                last_approval_x = 0
            else:
                last_approval_x = 1
        print(f"\nlast_approval_x={last_approval_x}")


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result - CheckBox checked]

There are two methods of accessing the state of the `CheckBox` widget. The first example is without kv file, and the second example is using kv file and Python script.

## Example 1 - without kv file

The following snippets does not use kv file and all widgets are added in Python script.

### Snippets - Py

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        Screen.__init__(self, **args)

        self.label_1 = Label(text...)
        self.label_2 = Label(text...)
        self.checkbox = CheckBox()

        self.add_widget(self.label_1)
        self.add_widget(self.label_2)

    def set_approval_rating(self):
        if last_approval_SUM == 5:
            last_approval_x = 1
        elif self.checkbox.active:    # checkbox checked i.e. True
            last_approval_x = 0
        else:
            last_approval_x = 1
```

## Example 2 - with kv file

The following snippets use kv file and all widgets are added in Python script.

### Snippets - kv

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: label_1
            text: "Label 1's text"
        Label:
            id: label_2
            text: "Label 2's text"
        CheckBox:
            id: checkbox
```

### Snippets - Py

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def set_approval_rating(self):
        if last_approval_SUM == 5:
            last_approval_x = 1
        elif self.ids.checkbox.active:    # checkbox checked i.e. True
            last_approval_x = 0
        else:
            last_approval_x = 1
```

### [Kivy » CheckBox](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html)

> `CheckBox` is a specific two-state button that can be either checked
>   (`active` has a  value of True) or unchecked (`active` has a value of
>   False).

### [Kivy CheckBox » active](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html#kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox.active)

> ```
> active
> ```
>
> Indicates if the switch is active or inactive.
>
> `active` is a [BooleanProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.BooleanProperty) and defaults to False.

Comment: When I try to run "self.ids.checkbox.active", it gives me the following error: TAKES 1 POSITIONAL ARGUMENT BUT 2 WERE GIVEN.

Comment: How did you invoke method `set_approval_rating`?

Comment: It seems for me it's missing something after "self"... This is how I tried: def checkbox_status_2(self):
        #if self.check_rates.active:
        if self.ids.check_rates.active:
            print('ACTIVE')

Comment: Please refer to updated post with a working example

Comment: If I use "instance" after self (def set_approval_rating(self, instance)), it stops asking for another argument. But it doesn't work either.

Comment: It's working now! 2 things I have done: I have put the builder with buttons and checkboxes before the main class. Also, I have removed the single-quotes from the ids of my checkboxes. One of these solved the issue :)   Thank you!